# Slick Slider Carousel with Recent post loop not working

Tags: php, post

I am trying to implement a recent posts carousel using Slick Slider and ACF.

I have found a great tutorial and followed the instructions here:

https://imranhsayed.medium.com/slick-slider-wordpress-without-plugin-slick-carousel-ef2394c737ef

and after MUCH trial and error I can get it to work as expected using some basic test content like this:

```
<div class="posts-carousel">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
</div>
```

But when I try and implement the code for the recent posts loop, I just get a white screen. I'm not great at php but I have tried to work out the issue and just I can't see it.

Another code example that is given works perfectly when copy and pasted:

```
<div class="posts-carousel px-5">
   <!--Slide One-->
   <div class="card">
      <img width="350" height="233" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="w-100" alt="alt-text">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h3 class="card-title">Your Post heading</h3>
         <p>Your Post Excerpt</p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View More</a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--Slide Two-->
   <div class="card">
      <img width="350" height="233" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="w-100" alt="alt-text">
      <div class="card-body">
         <h3 class="card-title">Your Post heading</h3>
         <p>Your Post Excerpt</p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View More</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But the code example for including a post loop does not

```
<?php
/**
 * Posts Carousel
 *
 * @package aquila
 */

$args = [
    'posts_per_page'         => 5,
    'post_type'              => 'post',
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
];

$post_query = new \WP_Query( $args );
?>
<div class="posts-carousel px-5">
    <?php
    if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) :
            $post_query->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="card">
                <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_custom_thumbnail(
                        get_the_ID(),
                        'featured-thumbnail',
                        [
                            'sizes' => '(max-width: 350px) 350px, 233px',
                            'class' => 'w-100',
                        ]
                    );
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x340" class="w-100" alt="Card image cap">
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <?php the_title( '<h3 class="card-title">', '</h3>' ); ?>
                    <?php aquila_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() ); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <?php esc_html_e( 'View More', 'aquila' ); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div>
```

I tried editing or removing the references to 'aquila' which I think is the theme the post writer it using but it did not work

I currently have this:

```
<?php

$args = [
    'posts_per_page'         => 2,
    'post_type'              => 'post',

];

$post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<div class="posts-carousel px-5">
    <?php
    if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) :
            $post_query->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="card">
                <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_custom_thumbnail(
                        get_the_ID(),
                        'featured-thumbnail',
                        [
                            'sizes' => '(max-width: 350px) 350px, 233px',
                            'class' => 'w-100',
                        ]
                    );
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x340" class="w-100" alt="Card image cap">
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <?php the_title( '<h3 class="card-title">', '</h3>' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div>
```

I have actually found a plugin that can do it for me, but I feel like I am so close to getting it working, i just can't work it out.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. You can try change the name of thumbnail function :

```
<?php
       if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) :
          while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) :
             $post_query->the_post();
             ?>
             <div>
                 <div class="card">
                    <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                       the_post_thumbnail(
                          get_the_ID(),
                          'featured-thumbnail',
                          [
                             'sizes' => '(max-width: 350px) 350px, 233px',
                             'class' => 'w-100',
                          ]
                       );
                    } else {
                       ?>
                       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x340" class="w-100" alt="Card image cap">
                       <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <?php the_title( '<h3 class="card-title">', '</h3>' ); ?>
                       <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                       <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() ); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">
                          <?php esc_html_e( 'View More', 'aquila' ); ?>
                       </a>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
          <?php
          endwhile;
       endif;
       wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32398071)